# AngularJS/Spring: Why [$http:baddata] error keep appearing even the data has successfully added to the database?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I've created a simple AngularJS and Spring program to test if I can connect both view and model.

The data from client side application are successfully added to the database, but the `[$http:baddata]` error is still there.

Here's the Spring controller of my program that handle the insertion:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/employee", consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public String addNewEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, String dateOfBirth, String gender, String address, String phoneNumber, String pictureUrl) {
    employeeService.addNewEmployee(firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, gender, address, phoneNumber, pictureUrl);
    return "Data has been added to the database.";
}
```

This is the code of my Controller in AngularJS (.js) file that already inside my app module controller:

```
$scope.emp = {
    firstName   : '',
    lastName    : '',
    dateOfBirth : '',
    gender      : '',
    address     : '',
    phoneNumber : '',
    pictureUrl  : ''
};

$scope.addNewEmployee = function() { 

    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/employee', $scope.emp)
    .then(function(response) {

        console.log(response);
        console.log("Data has been added to the database");
    }, function(error){

        console.log(error);
        console.log($scope.emp);
    });
};
```

I've also tried to insert these code inside my module config:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.unshift($httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider.$get());
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

The data `$scope.emp` itself is inserted when I checked it in the H2 Console, and my Spring application doesn't return any error.

What is the cause of this problem? Any comment/answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is better to design your API to accept POSTs using JSON data. URL encoding is dated and has limitations.

Comment: What does the Network Tab in the Developer Console say for the Content-Type of the response?

Comment: @georgeawg The response in the Network Tab show exactly the same as the Spring controller since it returns string which is `Data has been added to the database`. Indicating the data has been succesfully added to the db.